# delete $window.sessionStorage.token seems to be not working when logout is preformed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, jwt

I Have application built using angularjs,nodejs,which is authenticating using jwt token based authentication when we logout of the applicatoin users will be redirected to login page but once i login the url is some thing like

If i copy this url and paste in the same tab of the browser the user can see the authenticate resources I am not  sure is this how  the implementation should be

```
$scope.logout(){
        **delete $window.sessionStorage.token;//this seems to be not working**
//change to homgepage

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the ** doing in front of the delete keyword? Is that something you added just to highlight the code that doesn't seem to work? If not, please could you remove the ** from before the delete keword and re-test

Comment: Thanks for u reply i have used ** to highlight the code

Comment: It was a silly question, but I had to check ☺

Comment: please check and let me know

Comment: Why do you think the token is stored within "sessionStorage.token"? Maybe it is stored within "localStorage" or a different property? Or maybe it is not stored at all and fetched each time AngularJS app is loaded via OAuth flow based on an existing external cookie which you even do not see?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.logout(){
    delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
   //clear all dataSession
}
```